# How to get filename using FormData object?

Tags: javascript, form-data

**HTML**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id='photo_details'>
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_pic">
    <button class="btn">Save</button>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**
when I click submit of the form then given below javascript runs -

```
let form_details = document.getElementById("photo_details");
let form_data = new FormData(form_details);

// getting form values as key-value pair
        for ([key, value] of form_data.entries()) {
            console.log(key + ': ' + value);
        }
```

Suppose I gave f_name as 'Carl' and profile_pic as 'my_passport.png' then
**OUTPUT**
f_name: Carl
profile_pic: [object File]

**Problem in output -**
I got the value of `f_name` but
I am not getting the  value of key `profile_pic` instead I am getting `[object File]`.

How to get file name using FormData object.

**Help here !**

Comment: Is that only for `console`? If so, don't concatenate to string but use multiple params: `console.log(key ,  value);`. This way you'll have the actual File object getting logged, and you'll be able to navigate it to get its `name` property.

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: It worked.. Some times I really forget for silly mistakes #myMistake

Comment: Thanks.. So this question is over here !

Answer (score 3):

The form contains two inputs, one of type `text` and the other one of type `file` which means that the `FormData` instance will have two entries, one that has a `string` value and the other one a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) value.

To get the file's name, you can check if the current entries value if an instance of `File` and access its `name` property. Here is an example:

```
for ([key, value] of form_data.entries()) {
  let val;
  if (value instanceof File) {
    val = value.name;
  } else {
    val = value;
  }
  console.log(key + ': ' + val);
}
```

You can also get the file's name directly from the input, here is an example:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
const path = fileInput.value;
const fileName = path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
console.log('File name:', fileName);
```

This second example will only work if there is only one input of type file in the entire document.

Comment: `fileInput.value` will not return the file name

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, it will contain the entire path. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Nope, it will contain a fake-path, which is unusable and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return getData()" method="post" id='photo_details'>
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_pic" id="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getData() {
        let file_path = document.getElementById('file').value;
        let file_name = file_path.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
        console.log(file_name);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
form_data.get('profile_pic').name
```

```js
photo_details.onchange = () => {
  let form_data = new FormData(photo_details);  
  let fileName = form_data.get('profile_pic').name;
  console.log({fileName});
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id='photo_details'>
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_pic">
    <button class="btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id='photo_details'>
    <input type="text" name="f_name">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_pic">
    <button class="btn" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
</form>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){
    let form_details = document.getElementById("photo_details");
    let form_data = new FormData(form_details);
     for ([key, value] of form_data.entries()) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
</script>
```

Tested and works.